# scp vs netatalk, samba, and/or vsftpd with External USB drive

Tags: performance, linux, scp, netatalk

I set up a ubuntu server machine to share an ext2 formatted external usb drive. When attempting to copy a single 275MB files from said device through netatalk, I get estimated download rates at around 45 min. With samba and ftp (using vsftpd) I get 1+ hours! Using scp to copy the file results in complete download within 5 minutes. Another option, ssh+cp from external device to ~ and then using netatalk to grab it from there results in a total time of arounf 7 minutes. Does anyone have a clue what is misconfigured?

Assuming that nothing is, is there any fs/pseudo-fs that would use the internal hdd as an intermediate location/onion-layer for the external hdd (for reads only)?

Details:
AppleVolumes.default: /mnt/ext USB allow:*username* cnidscheme:cdb options:usedots,upriv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, The drive is a Seagate (didn't think it mattered at the time)

explained here http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005886

Answer (score 0):

Hi could you please test write TO the drive, both locally from ~ and from the network.

Secondly, can you please check top/ps to see what the load is when doing the samba copy in both directions.

Lastly, I'm guessing you haven't tried this from a windows client; either smb/ftp would be helpful.

Comment: I only have mac and linux machines. I'll try to get the performance stuff later tonight...